# How do I configure GitHub to use non-supported Jekyll site plugins?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions

I just created a great gallery for my Jekyll blog which builds perfectly on my localhost:4000. However, GitHub pages doesn't support the Jekyll Gallery Generator plug-in I am using: https://github.com/ggreer/jekyll-gallery-generator

I read about the alternative method of hosting Jekyll on a traditional host using FTP (uploading the _site directory) http://jekyllrb.com/docs/deployment-methods/ However, rather than reconfigure my entire site and hosting, It would be great if GitHub Pages could be used somehow even though I'm using a non-supported plugin.

What is a workaround for this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Depending if you deal with a User/Organization (**UO**) site or a Project site (**P**), do :

1. from your working folder `git init`
2. `git remote add origin git@github.com:userName/userName.github.io.git` (**UO**) or `git remote add origin git@github.com:userName/repositoryName.git` (**P**)
3. `jekyll new .` creates your code base
4. in *_config.yml*, set the *baseurl* parameter to `baseurl: ''` (**UO**) or `baseurl: '/repositoryName'` (**P**)
5. in *.gitignore* add **_site**, it will be versioned in the other branch
6. `jekyll build` will create the destination folder and build site.
7. `git checkout -b sources` (**UO**) or `git checkout master` (**P**)
8. `git add -A`
9. `git commit -m "jekyll base sources"` commit your source code
10. `git push origin sources` (**UO**) or `git push origin master` (**P**) push your sources in the appropriate branch
11. `cd _site`
12. `touch .nojekyll`, this file tells gh-pages that there is no need to build
13. `git init` init the repository
14. `git remote add origin git@github.com:userName/userName.github.io.git` (**UO**) or `git remote add origin git@github.com:userName/repositoryName.git` (**P**)
15. `git checkout master` (**UO**) or `git checkout -b gh-pages` (**P**) put this repository on the appropriate branch
16. `git add -A`
17. `git commit -m "jekyll first build"` commit your site code
18. `git push origin master` (**UO**) or `git push origin gh-pages` (**P**)

You now have something like [Octopress](http://octopress.org/docs/) does. Look at their rake file, there are some nice comments inside.

Comment: Thanks David, great answer! My site is now running the gallery with the workflow you described: http://raisingthelittleone.com/ I do want to mention, however,  that if you are using a custom domain (such as I am) even the Project Pages baseurl stays as a blank string.

Comment: Thanks David. It's an amazing step forward in life. Baby.create!(name: "Luna") =D

Comment: this is a great detailed answer. but in step 15, case **UO**, you don't actually have to `git checkout master` since you'll be automatically this branch

Comment: if you have this setup, how do you keep the master sync with sources folder?

Comment: are you using two .gitignores here? one for each branch?

Comment: @HarryMoreno one .gitignore for me.

Comment: THANK YOU, you saved my day!

Answer (score 4):

Better way is to configure Travis to automate deployment of jekyll with non-supported plugins. Follow [Travis getting started](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started/) guide to enable Travis for your repo.

Create `script/cibuild` with the following content

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e # halt script on error

bundle exec jekyll build
touch ./_site/.nojekyll # this file tells gh-pages that there is no need to build
```

Create `.travis.yml` with the following content (modify as required)

```
language: ruby
rvm:
- 2.3.3

before_script:
 - chmod +x ./script/cibuild # or do this locally and commit

# Assume bundler is being used, therefore
# the `install` step will run `bundle install` by default.
script: ./script/cibuild

# branch whitelist, only for GitHub Pages
branches:
  only:
  - master

env:
  global:
  - NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=true # speeds up installation of html-proofer

sudo: false # route your build to the container-based infrastructure for a faster build

deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  keep-history: true
  local_dir: _site/  # deploy this directory containing final build
  github_token: $GITHUB_API_KEY # Set in travis-ci.org dashboard
  on:
    branch: master
```

**Deployment steps (after every push):**

1. Build will be created using our custom script `script/cibuild` in `_site` directory
2. `_site` will be pushed to `gh-pages` branch.
3. github pages will serve site as it is without building it again (because of `.nojekyll` file)

**Reference:** My repository https://github.com/armujahid/armujahid.me/ is using this method for continuous integration using Travis CI