# Jekyll on github pages showing error: 404 Index.html not found (window)?

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I set up a static website using Jekyll in window 7 when i push my code to github and add gh-pages branch it says 404 not found error index.html not found.
while i already  added index.html in my root.
github repo:
[github Repo link](https://github.com/jazib-bashir/Runjekyll)

https://github.com/jazib-bashir/Runjekyll

Github Page Link [Github page Runjekyll](http://jazib-bashir.github.io/Runjekyll)

http://jazib-bashir.github.io/Runjekyll

I more thing: I use Rouge gem for highlighter not Pygments..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `rouge` and it's still not supported by github pages ([see dependency versions](https://pages.github.com/versions/)). This cause a build failure. You may receive a mail from Github about that.

If you want Github to build your site, you have to use `pygments` instead.

The other solution is to build locally and to push the `_site` content to github. [See my workflow description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249255/how-do-i-configure-github-to-use-non-supported-jekyll-site-plugins/28252200#28252200)

Comment: ok i try to use paygments thanks for pointing this out.
plz explain 2nd solution in details:
i build locally and _site folder is generated in root folder from where localhost show me blog how to put content to github??