# GH Pages + Jekyll: Images in subfolders?

Tags: image, jekyll, github-pages

Is there any reason that images inside a subfolder wouldn't be available via GH Pages? I've got Jekyll building out the _site folder, and everything seems to be working fine, but a couple of my images won't show up. The structure:

`_site
  /images
    /thumbnails
    /medium
    file.jpg
    file2.jpg
    etc...`

The images inside the parent /images folder work just fine. When I try to call the /thumbnails or /medium images I get a 404.

Here is the repo, showing the images in place: https://github.com/clarklab/chowdown/tree/gh-pages/_site/images

Here is [an image](http://chowdown.io/images/broccoli-beer-cheese-soup.jpg) on GH Pages from the parent folder, working just fine, and [here is a thumbnail](http://chowdown.io/images/thumbnail/broccoli-beer-cheese-soup.jpg), giving me a 404.

This isn't the usual "check your paths inside your templates" issue, these are actual images paths returning a 404. Anyone seen this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing the content in _site directory. http://chowdown.io/images/broccoli-beer-cheese-soup.jpg refers to the top level images directory and not the images inside _site.

Comment: _site isn't part of the URL structure though. The image you linked worked, which means calling from that directory is correct, no?

Comment: On the gh-pages branch you only need to have the contents of the _site folder committed on top level. All the other content should not be on that branch because they are not what the github page is supposed to be displaying

Answer (score 0):

Once you push your code to github, github pages generates you site and push the result on a web server. Uploading `_site` to your repository is useless as it's not used at all when serving http://chowdown.io/.

As I see that you have a plugins, you certainly need to generate you site locally and push the result (content of _site folder) to your repository.

In this case you'll have to store you code in `master` and the generated files in `gh-pages`. You also have to add an empty `.nojekyll` file at the root of your repository (gh-pages) in order to instruct gh-pages not to generate your site, but copy all your files as static files on the web server.

You can find a step by step versioning scheme here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28252200/1548376.

Comment: Aha! That's gotta be it. I was compiling and then commiting to gh-pages, didn't even realize I was supposed to let Github do it for me (put it in gh-pages).