# Point github repo to gh-pages not master

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions

My old website was simple jekyll code kept on master. Now, I revamped website and also started using `jekyll-assets` plugin. I just came to know that, github pages doesn't support custom plugins, so, I'm in trouble since I've used it at many places.

Now, I've found [work around](http://ixti.net/software/2013/01/28/using-jekyll-plugins-on-github-pages.html) to create a gh-pages branch and push compiled version over there. Earlier, I was not doing it since, github pages was using master to compile jekyll code.

I've also include `.nojekyll` in my master to not compile jekyll code - that didn't help either, github pages is still pointed to master.

Is there any way I can change this pointing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I configure GitHub to use non-supported Jekyll site plugins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249255/how-do-i-configure-github-to-use-non-supported-jekyll-site-plugins)

Comment: @DavidJacquel - yes it is similar. I found its not possible to do like that :) thanks though.

Comment: @MaulikSuchak a suggestion, perhaps to automate the process you can have your source on a branch, then use travis-ci to actually build and push to master? Travis ci is used to test, but nothing is stopping from using it to push the generated static site to master. This might help: http://eshepelyuk.github.io/2014/10/28/automate-github-pages-travisci.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to GitHub documentation if we've something like `username.github.io` it will point to master, it **will NOT** track `gh-pages` even if we want to, (so your jekyll code should be in the master in this case), for Projects repo, your published code has to be under `gh-pages` branch.

As of now I followed a great trick mentioned [here](http://ixti.net/software/2013/01/28/using-jekyll-plugins-on-github-pages.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your website is hosted in a [User & Organization Page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user--organization-pages) – that is in a dedicated repository named `username.github.io` – then GitHub Pages will *always* serve content [from the `master` branch](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user--organization-pages):

> Content from the `master` branch will be used to build and publish
>   your GitHub Pages site.

Since you can't force your GitHub Pages to build your site from another branch than `master` , I suggest you keep working on your new website in the `gh-pages` branch and merge it to `master` once you're done. Also, you should keep the `.nojekyll` file in your repository so GitHub Pages won't generate the site but instead serve your static files.

Comment: We both posted same thing on same time. Thanks @Enrico Campigogilo!