# Use 'jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin' with GitHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

How to use ['jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin'](https://github.com/Anthony-Gaudino/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin) on GitHub Pages?

It works locally, but I get the following error when I push my sources to GitHub:

```
The tag `t` on line 6 in `about.html` is not a recognized Liquid tag.
```

The code causing the error is:

```
{% t about.title %}
```

Comment: Is it still unsupported?

Comment: Check the David's post below(the first link)

Comment: @PavelShlepnev you can use "full" Jekyll (instead of one provided by github pages) with any plugins you need using github actions. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62730888/4752653

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GitHub Pages allow a limited set of plugins. You can find a list [here](https://pages.github.com/versions/) with the versions for each plugin.

In order to run your jekyll site locally in an environment similar to GitHub Pages, you should serve it with plugins disabled, using:

```
jekyll serve --safe
```

There are ways to make Jekyll multilingual without plugins, e.g. [this implementation](https://github.com/sylvaindurand/jekyll-multilingual) based on [this article](https://github.com/sylvaindurand/jekyll-multilingual).

If you really want to use plugins, you will have to generate your web pages locally, and push them into your GitHub repository instead of the Jekyll sources.

Comment: Both latest links are dead, any new source on that?

Comment: @KISKE https://sylvaindurand.org/making-jekyll-multilingual/

Answer (score 2):

On Github pages only following gems are allowed : https://pages.github.com/versions/

If you want to use any other gems you can :

- build locally and push to gh-pages branch on github pages ([see this for git setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28252200/1548376))
- setup a [continuous integration](https://github.com/integrations/feature/continuous-integration) that will take care of building and publishing for you
- use a service like [netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)