# Alias not producing expected result

Tags: git, bash, jekyll, alias

In my .bashrc I have the following alias setup:

```
alias sitebuild='bundle exec jekyll build; git checkout gh-pages; git rm * && mkdir temp && mv * temp/ && mv temp/_site/* . && rm -rf temp && touch .nojekyll; git status; git add .; git commit -am "update"; git push --all origin'
```

A bit of explanation as to why I want to do this: I'm building a site using Jekyll and `gh-pages`, except that I've started using plugins not supported by GitHub and so I have to build the site locally and push it to the repo (instead of letting GH build the site for me remotely).

My system is the following: I work on my site on branch `static_build`, make my commits and build `_site/` (containing all the final HTML). I then need to copy the contents of `static_build:_site/` over to `gh-pages:_site/` and *push that and that only*.

As far as I understand, the above command `sitebuild` should do that for me (and indeed **it does when I run every argument separately in the shell**); yet, it doesn't.

Any idea why?

---

**EDIT:** I have a feeling it might have to do with

```
mv * temp/
```

which, when I run every command individually, outputs

```
mv: rename temp to temp/temp: Invalid argument
```

It seems that in this case the terminal complains but still complies (`ls` shows that there is only `temp` left in the directory), but maybe this is no longer true when the alias is run?

**EDIT 2:** using instead

```
mv `ls -A | grep -v temp` ./temp
```

resolves the error of moving the folder inside itself, but not the main issue.

Comment: you probably want `&&` instead of `;` - in case one of your component commands fails, you probably don't want to continue.

Comment: Have you tried executing all commands as a single line (with the semi-colons and all) in an interactive shell, exactly like they appear in the whole alias?  Maybe this would fail too, and help you pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: @Fred see the edit :/

Comment: Are you in the right directory when executing the alias?  There is no `cd` in your alias.  Please note that the error you are listing for `mv` is possibly due to the fact that a directory cannot be moved inside itself.

Comment: Pretty sure `mkdir temp; mv * temp` will always fail.

Comment: @BenjaminW. works for me on the command line

Comment: I get "mv: cannot move 'temp' to a subdirectory of itself, 'temp/temp'".

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should really be using a function instead of an alias.

Comment: @chepner How would I write that?

Comment: Your Edit 2 assumes that you don't have any files containing the substring `test` in their names, and also assumes (probably correctly, but still) that none of your file names contain newlines.

Comment: I recommend doing this: push your site to github master branch, set up travisci to compile it and generate the site in the gh-pages branch. I've used this approach in several sites and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, *a* problem (if not *the* problem) is the attempt to move `temp` into itself. One way to avoid that (and replacing your alias with a shell function) is to make your temporary directory something that `*` won't match. Assuming you are not using `bash`'s `dotglob` option:

```
sitebuild () {
    bundle exec jekyll build
    git checkout gh-pages
    git rm * -r --ignore-unmatch &&
      mkdir .temp && mv * .temp/ && mv .temp/_site/* . && rm -rf .temp &&
      touch .nojekyll
    git status
    git add .
    git commit -am "update"
    git push --all origin
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is still not working. I think the directory moving and deleting is not happening properly. That might actually be caused by `git rm *`...

Comment: Yup, 'twas `git rm *`. In fact, I needed to do `git rm -r --ignore-unmatch *` to both recursively remove the files and not crash (as was the case) when trying to `git rm` a file that hadn't been `git add` (such as the whole `_site` directory...). Edit your answer accordingly and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

> [automatically] building a site using Jekyll and gh-pages (...) locally and push it to the repo

### OP `temp` issue

first I think that the use of `temp` itself, is a susceptible source of problems

```
mv * .temp/               
&& mv .temp/_site/* .        # keep the generated _site folder
&& rm -rf .temp              # and remove ALL the jekyll sources!
&& touch .nojekyll`
```

running the above command from the source folder will remove all the sources, needed to rebuild the site.

### General solution

1. build from the source folder: `./`
2. go to destination folder: `_site/`, and push its content to your deploy_branch: `gh-pages`
3. optionally, go back to source folder, source branch: `static_build`

with the following command:

```
# 1
bundle exec jekyll build
# 2
&& cd _site
&& git checkout -b gh-pages
&& touch .nojekyll
&& git add . && git commit -am "update"
&& git push origin gh-pages
# 3
&& cd ../ && git checkout -b static_build
```

(aside: the command above should be one-liner, remove the `#`, and remove `line break`  or escape it with `\` to make it work)

for a detailed explanation of How to configure GitHub to use non-supported Jekyll site plugins, check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28252200/2245329)

### + automate the deployment process with [Rake](https://github.com/ruby/rake).

[rake](https://github.com/ruby/rake) is a simple ruby build program, that will give you more control over the building tasks. so you can exit early in case of error, or don't update if the git repo is clean.

- add a [Rakefile](https://ruby.github.io/rake/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html) to the main folder
- define your tasks inside it (eg. `deploy` task )
- deploy by running `rake deploy` or just `rake` if you defined "deploy" as default task.

**e.g** a simple `Rakefile` that may help you doing the above.

```ruby
# == Helpers ======================================

# return `false` in case of error
#        `nil`   if git output doesn't contain "clean"
#        "clean" (a truthy value) if it contains it
def clean?
  puts status = `git status`
  clean = ($? == 0) && status.match(/clean/)
end

# == Tasks ========================================

task :build do
  system "bundle exec jekyll build"
end

task :deploy => [:build] do

  Dir.chdir("_site") do

    system "git checkout -b gh-pages"

    exit if clean? == false
    unless clean?
      system "git add . && git commit -am 'update'"
    end

    system "git push --all origin"
  end
end
```