# is it possible to push contents of Jekyll build folder to root of a repository?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I would like to have a personal website on Github pages but I can't properly push and publish because there is a problem with Owl Carousel and some error is thrown https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1913
I don't even use Lazyload as it is stated there but I have tried fixing it with `Lazyload: true`, it still doesn't work.

I am using `Jekyll build` to generate `_site` folder and everything works fine there when I check at localhost, I just need to move website to Github pages. This folder is deleted and regenerated with every build so I guess I can't do `git init` and start repo from there since everything there will be deleted each time I want to make a change.

Is it possible to only commit and push contents of `_site` folder to root of a repository each time? I could set `.gitignore` for everything excerpt `_site` folder but how to push its contents to the root?
Website should be accessible at `https://myname.github.io`

Or is there anything else I could do?

Comment: This worked three years ago : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28252200/1548376

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic types of GitHub Pages sites: Project Pages sites, and User and Organization Pages sites.

To create a User Pages site, name the repository `username.github.io` so that your website is accessible at http://username.github.io