# split and push committed files to two different branches

Tags: bash, git, sh, github-pages, vuepress

I would like to create a website with VuePress and deploy it with Github Pages. Luckily VuePress is able to generate a **dist** folder with all the required .html files. This folder is located at (from root) **./docs/.vuepress/dist** so I could take all the files from that folder and deploy them.

Unfortunately Github Pages can only deploy files from the master branch

https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages

and it is not possible to configure a specific folder for the build files. I thought about the following solution:

Create a "dev" branch next to the master branch and keep the files from the dist folder in the master branch and have the project in the dev branch.

I started learning using Git on the terminal and created a **publish.sh** file to commit and push the project to the Github repository.

```
git add *
git commit -m "."
git push origin master
```

How can I enhance my shell script to do the following (if possible)

```
git add *
git commit -m "."

git push -- all files -- origin dev

git push -- all files of the dist folder -- origin master
```

Comment: You can try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28252200/1548376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by having two sandboxes pointing to the same GitHub repo, one with your `dev` branch checked out, where you modify the files, and one with your `master` branch checked out, for updating the dist files.

Here I'm assuming `<repo>` already exists on GitHub, but it may or may not have branches yet.

Set up your `dev` branch where you edit your code:

```
git clone <repo> repo.dev
cd repo.dev
git checkout -b dev  # remove -b if origin/dev exists
# edit, commit, edit, commit, edit, commit
git push --set-upstream origin dev # remove --set-upstream if you removed -b above
```

Set up your `master` branch where you publish your code:

```
cd ..
git clone <repo> repo.dist
cd repo.dist
git checkout -b master # remove -b if origin/master exists
# copy the .vuepress/dist directory into this sandbox as required for deployment
git add .
git commit -m 'initial dist'
git push --set-upstream origin master # remove --set-upstream if you removed -b above
```

Now, the next time you want to make a change:

```
cd ../repo.dev
# edit, commit, edit, commit, edit, commit
# make vuepress update repo.dist/.vuepress/dist,
# possibly by symlinking it from your repo.dev sandbox.
cd ../repo.dist
git commit -a -m'updated dist'
git push
```

Now, this solution has exactly the weakness @NitsanAvni mentioned in a comment to his answer: the `master` and `dev` branches have nothing in common, not even their initial commit. So this might not be better than having two repos, but it does keep things together, which I can see could be convenient.

Note: you need two separate sandboxes, even if you have just one remote repo, because otherwise it is impossible to have up-to-date views on different branches simultaneously in the same sandbox.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe add an additional repo inside the `dist` folder, which will be synced to the Github Pages repo, only containing the relevant files.

can do it with:

```
$ cd dist
$ git init
$ git remote add origin <github-pages-repo>
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: So you think it's not possible with only one repo?

Comment: I guess it's possible, but probably will need to jump through some hoops in order to modify the folder structure. Also the two branches would have nothing in common; it's as if they're on separate repos anyway. I wouldn't recommend it.