# How can I make my blog show as it is shown on bundler?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am making my Github blog with Jekyll theme(Centrarium) and I found that it works differently with my bundler.
I can see my posts on the main page built with bundler but I can't see them on the real web page. 
Here are more descriptions.

https://syh39.github.io/test/2020/02/29/test.html

I've tried downloading the theme again but the initialized version of Centrarium also works like this(posts show on the main page with bundler, but does not show on the real web page)

What should I do to make my web page the same as it is shown on the bundler?

Answer (score 1):

If you compare your [Gemfile](https://github.com/syh39/syh39.github.io/blob/master/Gemfile) to [github-pages allowed gems](https://pages.github.com/versions/), you can see that both **jekyll-archives** and **jekyll-paginate-v2** are not supported.

Possible workarounds for pagination :

- use the no longer supported [jekyll-paginate](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/) ;

Possible workarounds for pagination and archives :

- deploy your jekyll code and generated site in two separates branches and publish generated site's branch on gh-pages ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249255/how-do-i-configure-github-to-use-non-supported-jekyll-site-plugins)) ;
- deploy your site on plaforms like [netlify](https://netlify.com) which allow custom plugins use.